# Jquery Submit and reload result

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I use function with jquery for post form and get results

**My code it´s :**

```
function click_post(id)
{
    $("#form_order_sel_"+id).submit( function () {  
        $.ajax({   
            type: "POST",
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,  
            url: "indexer_adm.php", 
            success: function(data){
                $("#load_order").html(data); 
            }   
        });   
        return false; 
    }); 
}
```

The problem it´s i need update the div , i try different mthods but i can´t get this because if i put setTimeOut for reload the div , the post no works , etc

**I think the problem it´s here :**

```
$("#load_order").html(data);
```

Howewer i need one line more for get update with the new content when i use POST method with jquery

**Thank´s Regards !!!**

Comment: it sounds like you aren't sending back the proper response data based on form data submitted and problem is in your php. WHat does the php look like that process the ajax data

Comment: not able to see the click event. can you paste it here? Is that inline?

Comment: not clear also if you are getting anything back currently( or if ajax occurs) .. does `$("#load_order").html(data); ` do anything currently?

Comment: can you update "indexer_adm.php" code ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few points to consider for this issue,

1. Check the data that is being posted by calling $(this).Serialize()
2. What is the return type from the php file, in case of html markup this should workfine, else in case of JSON Data, you should use JSON.parse(data) prior to using this.
3. try to use the chrome debugger and find what data you are getting as a response to the AJAX call that you make and give us those details along with the status of the check points to guide further.